# How to replace images in TXTextControl.web

Tags: javascript, txtextcontrol

I'm trying to replace an image using TXTextControl.web, but couldn't find a way to do so.

TXTextControl C# has ImageDoubleClicked event, I didn't find such a function in javascript APIs.

Maybe I overlooked javascript APIs. Any suggestions? Many thanks!

Comment: I assume you might be talking about this 3rd party product: [TX Text Control .NET](https://www.textcontrol.com/products/windows-forms/tx-text-control-dotnet/overview/)?  Q: Have you opened a support call, or reviewed the site's documentation?

Comment: Yes, that's the product. I didn't open a support call, but did check their documentation. However couldn't find any API to replace an image.